# TPT entities derived from TPH base classes in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first, tph

I have a project that is using EF6 Database first mapped to a SQL database.  This is all new so I control the EF model as well as the database schema.

I currently have a table that I'll call Vehicle for simplicity.  I use a discriminator column to get subclass Entities Car and Truck.  This all works fine.

Now I need to do a 'soft delete' and move any deleted vehicles to a VehicleHistory table. (After trying this w/ EF i will probably use a SQL transaction).  This needs to be reviewable so I need this history table mapped as well, but I would like to keep it within the inheritance hierarchy so its easily reused in other classes.

My idea was to create 'vehiclecurrent' and 'vehiclehistory' tables with FK's to Vehicle for shared columns. i would then use TPT in EF to get 'carcurrent','carhistory', ect... derived from my TPH classes(so e.g. carhistory->car->vehicle).  This is not working and I get Error 3034: "Entities w/ different keys are mapped to the same row"

So my question is basically how can I pull this off? Will this approach work and how, or is there another way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: First carefully contemplate whether or not you really need inheritance. Even without any paraphernalia, in an ORM the drawbacks of inheritance often outweigh the benefits. Consider other behavioral patterns, like Strategy. I think in your case, inheritance complicates things enormously. With a straightforward table it's trivial. But if you really want this, an easier alternative could be a TPH history table.

Comment: thanks @Gert Arnold, if I did use these as separate entities, what is the best way to interchange these in code? The entities will have little behavior (more gridview updating properties stuff) and I'm trying to get my mind around an interface for these without duplicating all the properties

Comment: I'd have to know your data to say anything sensible about this. If the subtypes you intended to introduce don't differ too much you could suffice with just one `Vehicle` table, having some "type" column, but without actually creating subtypes.